# checking value entered by user

Tags: c

With this code I am trying to check whether the value of I given correctly by the user or not. When I give integer value the program work perfectly and `"done "` gets printed on the screen but when i give a character such as `"a"` then it goes into an infinite loop and do not input the value again....

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{   
    int i;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    while(!scanf("%d",&i))
    {
        printf("no ");
    }
   printf("done\n");
   return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT 1:

```
Enter an integer: 5
done
```

OUTPUT 2:

```
Enter an integet: a
no no no no no no no no no no no no....upto infinite times
```

Comment: `"a"` is not a character, but a string.

Comment: i wrote "a" just to make clear that it makes difference in the paragraph...

Comment: I suspected that, but this is read by absolute newbies, too. The code tags in markdown are normally for something you type literally. So `a` is sufficient (combined with the sample sessions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What couldn't be consumed is left on the stream, so you have to consume it before trying to read again.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{   
    int i;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    while(!scanf("%d",&i))
    {
        scanf("%*s"); /* add this line to consume the garbage on the stream */
        printf("no ");
    }
   printf("done\n");
   return 0;
}
```